# Why a class is hoisted wrongly inside another class constructor

Tags: javascript, scope, scoping, hoisting

I define a class Node, then I define a class LinkedList, inside the LinkedList constructor, I create a new Node. The problem is that if I run the two declarations at the same time, the second time I run the declaration even if the Node declaration was defined before the LinkedList, I got an error *Can't access Node before initialization*

```
class Node {}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    console.log(new Node());
  }
}

new LinkedList()
```

Notice it only happens if the code block is run at once, and it happens the second time I run in google chrome dev tools, and renaming Node as a function also removes the problem. I think this has to do with hoisting, but I'd like to understand why does it happen and how.

**Update**:
For those who say what does it mean to run it all at once, or it is not reproducible this is a gif of how I run the whole block at once, and how it fails

[image]

**Environment info**:
Google Chrome   80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    cf72c4c4f7db75bc3da689cd76513962d31c7b52-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#943}
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 8.0.426.25

Comment: I've just run this whole block in Chrome dev tools three times and it has succeeded every time.

Comment: Not clear how Hoisting would happen in this code. Not sure how you run it at the same time. Also Node has meaning in the browser.

Comment: @JLRishe - Could be a version thing. Lexical scope stuff in the console has been a bit of a moving target... :-)

Comment: @epascarello - Well, `class` bindings are hoisted (but not initialize), so...there's an *aspect* of scope...

Comment: For those wondering how to reproduce the issue, I just updated the question with a gif

Comment: Any reason you're using Chrome 80? It has been obsolete since April.

Comment: @JLRishe I think even with a way older chrome version that couldn't be the answer. ECMAScript is not different in that version, that doesn't answer the question at all :)

Comment: @Jhonatan As others have already explained to you, browser debug consoles have various quirks that can't be fully explained by ECMAScript standards. So yes, it's entirely possible that what you're seeing is a quirky behavior of Chrome 80's debug console. And I ask again: any reason you're using an obsolete version of Chrome? As I said in my first comment, I can't observe the behavior you're describing in Chrome 85.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Don't test non-trivial code in the devtools console. It's a highly unusual environment which can be a bit misleading. Instead, test code in actual modules/scripts (in files on your system, in tools like CodePen or CodeSandbox or jsFiddle, etc.)

### More Details

I can't replicate the behavior you've said you're seeing in my version of Chrome or Firefox; Chrome lets you redeclare those constants, and Firefox complains that they're already declared, which is what you'd get if you actually had

```
class Node { }

class Node { }
```

in a compilation unit (loosely, "file" or module). Having two `class` declarations with the same identifier name in the same scope is an error, whereas having two function declarations with the same identifier name in the same scope is not (the last one wins), which presumably accounts for the fact you didn't see this when you converted them to functions.

Some browser consoles may let you get away with it, either by just breaking the rules, or by creating nested anonymous scopes every time you post code, so it ends up being:

```
class Node { }

{
    class Node { }
}
```

and if you did `class Node { }` a third time:

```
class Node { }

{
    class Node { }

    {
        class Node { }
    }
}
```

and so on.

But that's an oddity of consoles. Which is why, again, it's best not to test non-trivial code in devtools consoles.